# How to use Spring Data Mongo distinct method with query and limit

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

Looking at the following code:

```
mongoOps.getCollection("FooBar")
        .distinct("_id", query(where("foo").is("bar")).limit(10).getQueryObject());
```

I would expect this to return only the first 10 distinct _ids of collection FooBar.
But unfortunately, running this against a Collection having more than 10 documents matching the criteria, it returns all of them ignoring the limit(10) specified here.

_id is an ObjectId.

How can I achieve this?
Is it a bug in Spring Data?

I'm already aware how I can achieve this using an aggregate but I'm trying to simplify the code if possible since using an aggregate takes many more lines of code.

FYI: I'm using Spring Data Mongodb 1.10.10 and unfortunately, updating is currently not an option.